# eBay REST API getOffers no results but returns order array in Trading API

Tags: ebay-api

I am stuck on this issue for weeks and I didn't have any replies on the eBay forum.

I searched many places on web and found some people having the same problem as mine but no one got an answer to solution.

Just wondering if anyone is using eBay REST API and you are getting some results through the **getOffers API**, maybe you can see if I missed anything.

> Things I confirmed through the Inventory API (**REST**)

1. I **successfully created** a couple of hundreds of inventory items through Inventory API.
2. I **successfully created** offers for all my items on eBay.
3. All items on eBay are showing the **correct quantity and price**.

> Things I have done manually through the eBay website as a general customer

1. I searched my items and opened one of them
2. I purchased a few items.
3. I marked all purchases as **payment sent**.

> Things I have done through the Fulfillment API (**REST**)

1. I sent the request to get all orders in the last 10 day.
2. The response header contains: `rlogid:t6pithqauq%60%28ciudbq%60anng%7Fu2h%3F%3Cwk%7Dukqjtcpse*1423455-15fb2623e27-0xb8`
3. The response body contains:

   ```
   {
       "href": "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?filter=creationdate:%5B2017-10-01T08:25:43.511Z..%5D&limit=50&offset=0",
       "total": 0,
       "limit": 50,
       "offset": 0,
       "orders": []
   }
   ```

> Things I have done to find out if items are sold

1. I refreshed the item page and confirm that eBay website is displaying **2 sold** just after I marked **payment send** on my purchase page.
2. I can see that all orders appear through the **Trading API** (**XML**).

Comment: Did you create these orders on the live eBay website? Your API calls looks like it's consuming the sandbox API rather than production (`https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/` should be `https://api.ebay.com/`).

Comment: Yes we use both sandbox and production APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Note: The Fulfillment API covers only the transactions that have completed the checkout process. This includes both paid purchases and purchases that do not require upfront payment (such as COD). However, the API does not cover pending payment purchases that require upfront payment before shipment."

Copied from here: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/fulfillment/overview.html

So PayPal is covered, COD or prepayment are not...

Better use Trading API.